# Loose Hub on front wheel

Tags: wheels, hub

Front wheel hub is loose and the whole thing wobbles a bit. Im a fan of dubstep but there's a little too much wubwub in my hub. How do I tighten that bad boy up properly?

Thanks!

Comment: http://sheldonbrown.com/cone-adjustment.html

Comment: In addition to Sheldon, Park Tool has a site that has some excellent maintenance instructions.

Comment: I think you've posted to the wrong SE. This one is Cycling - perhaps you wanted [Sound](http://sound.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of hub, but most commonly you'll need a 15mm and 17mm cone wrench.  A picture of the hub would be helpful.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the link to Sheldon Brown. I had the right idea, but not the proper wrenches. I'll see what I can do!

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful to check if the skewer is tightened properly too. See that a lot in the shop when customers bring their bikes back saying the wheel pulls to one side when they brake. They also have disc brakes, hence why it pulls to one side. :)

Comment: Upvoted because yeah, I did this when my disc-brake bike was brand-new...